# OnLongClick button listener android

Tags: android

Hello :) I am trying to detect when the user press a long click on the button and when he releases the long click so I am using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10746549/3953319 
I don't know why but the LongClickListener is called twice to me, here is my code:

```
button1.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View pView) {
        TimeCounter = 0;
        final Random rand = new Random();
        time = rand.nextInt(7) + 1;
        SecTime = time * 1000;
        CountDownTimer2 = new CountDownTimer(SecTime, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,
                            R.raw.windows_8_notify);
                mPlayer.start();
                t = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                                Thread.sleep(1);
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        TimeCounter++;
                                        textview.setText("Your reaction time:"
                                                    + TimeCounter + "MS");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                };
                t.start();
            }
        }.start();
        isSpeakButtonLongPressed = true;
        return true;
    }
});

button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View pView, MotionEvent pEvent) {
        pView.onTouchEvent(pEvent);
        if (pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (isSpeakButtonLongPressed) {
                if (mPlayer == null) {
                    textview.setText("You have released the button before the sound");
                    CountDownTimer2.cancel();
                } else {
                    t.interrupt();
                    t = null;
                    OldScore = sharedpreferences.getInt("HighScore", 0);
                    if (TimeCounter < OldScore) {
                        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putInt("HighScore", TimeCounter);
                        editor.commit();
                        textview1.setText("Your new High Score:"
                                    + TimeCounter + "MS");
                    }
                    textview.setText("Your reaction time:"
                                + TimeCounter + "MS");
                    mPlayer.pause();
                    mPlayer.reset();
                    mPlayer = null;
                }
                isSpeakButtonLongPressed = false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I ran the application and when I long click the button I hear the "windows_8_notify" twice, why is that? is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Y do You have two .start() in your code ?? I think thats the reason its running twice . please check and let me know

Comment: @user3716835 have you looked at the code? one for the CountDownTimer and one for the Thread.

Comment: You mean if you hold it down the OnLongClick functionality happens twice? Where are you setting the listener?

Comment: @zgc7009 yes it happens twice, I hear the voice twice, the thread runs twice (not at the same time) its like - sound, 2 seconds interval, sound again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is because in your `onTouchListener`'s `onTouch` method, you call `pView.onTouch(...)`, and then at the end, `return false`. The `return false` line indicates that your `onTouchListener` has not handled the `onTouch` event, so then it resorts to calling it's default `onTouch` function, which is identical to your `pView.onTouch(...)` call. However, the default function happens to also call your `onLongClickListener`'s `onLongClick` method. Thus, it calls `pView.onTouch(...)` twice, each time calling your `onLongClickListener`'s `onLongClick` method.

SO. I believe you can avoid this if you return `true` in the `onTouch` method in appropriate cases. In my mind, it would look something like this:

## Abbreviated

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View pView, MotionEvent pEvent) {
        boolean longClickOccurred = pView.onTouchEvent(pEvent);
        ...
        if (pEvent.getAction()...) {
            if (isSpeakButtonLongPressed) {
                ...
                longClickOccurred = true;
            }
        }
        return longClickOccurred;
    }
});
```

## Full Rewrite

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View pView, MotionEvent pEvent) {
        boolean longClickOccurred = pView.onTouchEvent(pEvent);
        if (pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (isSpeakButtonLongPressed) {
                if (mPlayer == null) {
                    textview.setText("You have released the button before the sound");
                    CountDownTimer2.cancel();
                } else {
                    t.interrupt();
                    t = null;
                    OldScore = sharedpreferences.getInt("HighScore", 0);
                    if (TimeCounter < OldScore) {
                        Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putInt("HighScore", TimeCounter);
                        editor.commit();
                        textview1.setText("Your new High Score:"
                                    + TimeCounter + "MS");
                    }
                    textview.setText("Your reaction time:"
                                + TimeCounter + "MS");
                    mPlayer.pause();
                    mPlayer.reset();
                    mPlayer = null;
                }
                isSpeakButtonLongPressed = false;
                longClickOccurred = true;
            }
        }
        return longClickOccurred;
    }
});
```

This will(should) stop your button from recalling the `pView.onTouchEvent(pEvent)`, without interfering with other click functions.

(In fact, I don't think you need the boolean variable `isSpeakButtonLongPressed`, because its value is basically identical to `longClickOccurred` when you assert that pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP. UNLESS 1) you use `isSpeakButtonLongPressed` outside of the `onTouch` function, or 2) you have some other `onClickListener` set or something like that, which will cause `pView.onTouchEvent(pEvent)` to return `true` when a long click has not occurred.)

Anyway, I hope the works/helps/was-not-a-convoluted-explanation. Good luck!

Comment: Wow , thx for the explanation, just one thing - I want to try your code but - the qEvent.getAction() is not working (it says Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean )

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I didn't want to retype everything you had, so I put in `...`'s where you code does its own thing. You only need to copy/paste in three lines; each line with the `longClickOccurred` variable appears.

Comment: Ok so I have done it, you can take a look here: http://pastebin.com/QDtBQXeR unfurtunately, still the same :( you can test it if you want to :) here is the xml file: http://pastebin.com/8GaHMNwq

Comment: remove the first pView.onTouchEvent(...) call. I just wrote a full rewrite, if you want to compare to that (or copy/paste it). It "should" work :\