# Open Dialog with LongClick and focus the Dialog

Tags: android

I want to simulate the iOS 3D Touch. I have a recyclerview, where i register a OnLongClickListener to every item. When a longClick is detected, a AlertDialog opens.
For checking if the longClick ends, i have implemented the OnTouchlistener.

In short, i implemented it like it was described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10746549/4907047

It works like a charm, as long as i don't move the finger after longClick. If i move the finger, the listview under the dialog is still moving with my finger. Besides that the dialog will not close after stop touching the screen.
I think i have to cancel the events of the underlying listview. Does anyone know, how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider implementing a **contextMenu** since it can do what you want. [Read this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu).

Comment: As i want images in my dialog, i don't think that a contextMenu can handle this?