# show alertdialog while i press the screen

Tags: java, android

i have a list with surveys and all those surveys contains a picture. when you finish a survey the app returns to the overview where i can see all completed and all uncompleted surveys and all rejected surveys.

**What i want:**

Now if i click long on the screen and the survey isnt rejected and is completed i want to get a preview of the picture as long as i press the screen and disappear if i release the screen.

**The problems are:**

- How can i cancel or dismiss a AlertDialog without adding a positive
  Button?
- Is it possible to get the MotionEvent without an onTouch Listener and
  just with longClickListener?

Here is my code with an onTouch and a longClick-listener and i want to eliminate one of them:

```
   row.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               row.setOnLongClickListener(l -> {
                            // V3.0 only execute long click if the survey hasn't been declined
                            if (getContext() instanceof SurveyListPatientActivity && !erhebung.rejected() && !erhebung.isCompleted()) {
                                ((SurveyListPatientActivity) getContext()).showRejectSurvey(erhebung);

                            }else if(getContext() instanceof SurveyListPatientActivity && !erhebung.rejected() && erhebung.isCompleted()){
                                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
                                byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(erhebung.getPic(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                                adb.setView(imageView);
                                adb.create().show();
                                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                                    // cancel AlertDialog
                                }
                            }
                            return true;
                        });
                        return false;
                }
        });
```

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:**

Whit the help of @brianoqr i changed my code into this.
Everything works fine but the Dialog dosent disappear.

```
row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
                byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(erhebung.getPic(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                adb.setView(imageView);
                dialog = adb.create();
                dialog.show();
                isLongPressed = true;
                return true;
            }
        });
        row.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                System.out.println("1");
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    System.out.println("2");
                    if (isLongPressed) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        System.out.println("canceld");
                        isLongPressed = false;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: It's your alert dialog get auto close when you touch outside the alert dialog?

Comment: yes it get auto closed

Comment: so what's the problem then? your alert is getting closed, no need to hold long to preview the image. Just show the alert dialog on long touch and rest it automatically done

Comment: also, you can simplify your code using directly onLongClickListener() method as:

``row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // your stuffs here
                
                return false;
            }
        });``

Comment: no if i release the finger the alert stay there till i press outside the window

Comment: row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() { @Override public boolean onLongClick(View v) { // your stuffs here return false; } });    does this detect when i release?

Comment: no, it doesn't. check the below answer

Comment: i've made an edit

Comment: Try this adb.setCancelable(true);

Comment: still the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably would do it differently, but to answer the question how to cancel a dialog with out a button:

```
AlertDialog dialog = adb.create();
dialog.show()
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
  dialog.dismiss()
}
```

The code you have written will not work as you want, the onlongpress is the leading action, you can structure your code something like in this ticket: [Android - Detect End of Long Press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183874/android-detect-end-of-long-press)

And your dialog will then need to be in a different scope to allow for automatic dismissal

**EDIT**

```
row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
          if(!isLongPressed){
            isLongPressed = true;
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
            byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(erhebung.getPic(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
            adb.setView(imageView);
            dialog = adb.create();
            dialog.show();
          }
            return true;
        }
    });
    row.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            System.out.println("1");
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                System.out.println("2");
                if (isLongPressed) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    System.out.println("canceld");
                    isLongPressed = false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: sorry should be dismiss()

Comment: hmm, as both cancel and dismiss should work... just to make sure your log messages are being printed, so the action_up is being executed?

Comment: yes i've a outprint below the cancel and this gets print

Comment: Okay, the issue is the long press is executing multiple times, i updating my answer